# 404 Not found error after update to WordPress 5.0

Tags: errors, 404-error

I have a WordPress website which was working good before WordPress 5.0. after update to WordPress 5.0 I get an 404 error on loading resources.

```
style.min-rtl.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and the missing file address is :

```
http://example.com/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min-rtl.css?ver=5.0.1
```

I am wondering why I got this error? in the older versions of WordPress there was not such a file or directory but I was not getting this error. I was hoping this will be fixed in the latest WP update v5.0.1 but it's not.

Is it a problem in my theme or WP or maybe something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I tried to disable all plugins and change theme to the default WordPress theme and error is showing yet.

Then tried to install a new WordPress 5.0.1 and got 2 errors:

```
theme.min-rtl.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
style.min-rtl.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I changed the WP language to English and the errors gone. and the errors comeback on all right to left languages. so it seems to be a WP issue and needs to be fixed in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file in WP 5.0.1 is "style-rtl.min.css" and not "style.min-rtl.css". 
So did you try to check for plugin of cache or optimization that would have wrongly rename it ?

Comment: I tried to disable all plugins and also changed theme to "Twenty Nineteen" and still getting the error. It seems to be a WP problem!